# prevent ggplotly to change the legends style created in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

Using the `ggplotly` function from the `plotly package`, I am making the `ggplot` output interactive. When I use the `ggplotly` function to a ggplot-generated plot, however, the legend style and data shapes are completely altered. How can I use `plotly` while maintaining the shapes and legends as the primary plot?

data:

```
"","Day","Drug","Sex","Y","DrugSex"
"1",1,"A","Female",2.192306074,"A,Female"
"2",1,"B","Male",4.551912798,"B,Male"
"3",1,"B","Female",1.574070652,"B,Female"
"4",1,"C","Female",-0.143946163,"C,Female"
"5",1,"A","Male",5.144422967,"A,Male"
"6",1,"C","Male",5.724705829,"C,Male"
"7",2,"A","Male",2.691617258,"A,Male"
"8",2,"B","Female",-3.0289955,"B,Female"
"9",2,"C","Male",0.338102762,"C,Male"
"10",2,"A","Female",-0.558581233,"A,Female"
"11",2,"B","Female",-2.942620032,"B,Female"
"12",2,"C","Male",1.024670497,"C,Male"
"13",3,"A","Male",2.264980803,"A,Male"
"14",3,"C","Female",2.103722883,"C,Female"
"15",3,"A","Female",2.091621938,"A,Female"
"16",3,"B","Male",1.535299922,"B,Male"
"17",3,"B","Male",1.618399767,"B,Male"
"18",3,"C","Female",0.136160703,"C,Female"
```

After copying you may need to run the following command to convert it to the dataframe:

```
df <- read.delim("clipboard", sep = ",")
```

Here is the data using the `dput` function:

```
df <-structure(list(Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Drug = c("A", "B", "B", "C", 
"A", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "B", "B", 
"C"), Sex = c("Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female"), Y = c(2.192306074, 
4.551912798, 1.574070652, -0.143946163, 5.144422967, 5.724705829, 
2.691617258, -3.0289955, 0.338102762, -0.558581233, -2.942620032, 
1.024670497, 2.264980803, 2.103722883, 2.091621938, 1.535299922, 
1.618399767, 0.136160703), DrugSex = structure(c(1L, 4L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L), levels = c("A,Female", 
"A,Male", "B,Female", "B,Male", "C,Female", "C,Male"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the code for generating the plot:

```
df_means <- df %>% group_by(DrugSex) %>% 
  summarise(color = first(Drug),Mean = mean(Y)) %>% 
  rename(grouping_var = 1) %>% mutate(x = seq(length(unique(grouping_var))))

p <-df %>% ggplot(aes(x = DrugSex, y = Y)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Drug, shape = DrugSex))+ 
  geom_segment(data = df_means, aes(x=x-0.25, xend=x+0.25, y=Mean, yend=Mean, color= 
  color),inherit.aes = F, show.legend = F)+
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
        legend.key=element_blank() #transparent legend panel
  )
```

I want my plotly to look like the `p`

[image]

However, after executing `ggplotly(p)`, it appears as follows:

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput`?

Comment: I updated the question with the data from the dput function @Quinten

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### update

To answer your question in comments...

If you wanted to drop the line segment legend (that you had set to false in `ggplot`) you could use the following:

```
fixLines <- function(plt) {
  lapply(1:length(plt$x$data),
         function(j) {
           if(plt$x$data[[j]]$mode == "lines") {
             plt$x$data[[j]]$showlegend <<- F
           }
         })
  plt
}
```

If you're using `fixHt`, you can call both or consolidate them.

To keep the Plotly legend, but drop the segments and move it to the bottom:

```
ggplotly(p) %>% fixLines() %>%
  layout(legend = list(orientation = 'h', xanchor = 'center', x = .5))
```

#### original content

I've got two methods you can work with. Both methods will eliminate the ability to use pointer events in the legend (where you click on the legend to show or hide information).

One method strictly uses R, has many steps, and is somewhat complicated.

The other method uses `htmlwidgets::onRender` and Javascript. This method is almost no work on your part.

The method that is strictly R does require finessing. It's also based on the assumption that you're using RStudio. It might work in other IDEs, but I'm not sure. Essentially you'll capture what's shown in the Viewer pane at one point. I have no idea how big your viewer pane is, so I can't tell you the numbers to use.

I've added a function that changes some Plotly defaults. For example, when you render into your browser or the viewer pane, it is set to `fill = True` (which will likely run your legend off the viewable area of the webpage). I've set the height to 80% to ensure the legend is shown. When we create the plot, this function is piped at the end. (You'll see it used in the code.)

```
fixHt <- function(plt) {
  plt <- plotly_build(plt) # ensure data object is in plt object
  plt$sizingPolicy$defaultHeight <- '100%'
  plt$sizingPolicy$padding <- '15'
  plt$sizingPolicy$browser$defaultWidth <- '100vw'  # 100% viewer width
  plt$sizingPolicy$browser$defaultHeight <- '100vh' # 100% viewer height
  plt$sizingPolicy$browser$fill <- F
  plt$sizingPolicy$viewer$fill <- F
  plt    # return the plotly object with these changes
}
```

#### Method 1: Strictly R

We'll create a second plot. Don't change your current plot; create a new one. In the new plot, we'll exaggerate the legend. The idea is to get a better resolution and to make the text relatively sized (versus the typical rendering).

In the end, a *picture* of your `ggplot2` legend will be added to your plot.

```
library(plotly)
library(cowplot)
library(magick)

# if using within R tools only -- 
#   start with enhancing the legend for clarity in transfer
p1 <- df %>% ggplot(aes(x = DrugSex, y = Y)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Drug, shape = DrugSex)) + 
  geom_segment(data = df_means, aes(x=x-0.25, xend=x+0.25, y=Mean, yend=Mean, color= 
                                      color),inherit.aes = F, show.legend = F)+
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
        legend.key=element_blank(), #transparent legend panel
        legend.key.size = unit(.5, 'cm'),
        legend.title = element_text(size = rel(1.2)), # relative text size
        legend.text = element_text(size = rel(1)))    # relative text size
```

Using `cowplot`, capture the legend. If you want to see it, you can use `cowplot::plot_grid(pLeg)` to print it to the plot pane.

```
pLeg <- get_legend(p1) # capture the legend
```

The next step will require you to watch exactly what happens in the Viewer pane. The code between `dev.off` and `dev.off` may have re-run a few times. (It depends on your settings.) I've added quite a few comments here that would behoove you to read and heed.

Essentially, you'll print the legend to the viewer pane while `magick`'s `image_graph` is listening. Whatever you see in the viewer pane will end up in the object `img`.

If when you run `dev.off` you see

> Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)

That means that you've cleared out everything. It means the same thing as when you see

```
null device 
          1
```

When you run this code, I suggest that you make your viewer pane really wide. You can move it back after `dev.off`.

```
# clear plot & viewer pane if not already**
dev.off() # should say 'null device' 
# if not re-exacute until it does
# if it says it 'can't`, continue
autoviewer_enable()
# super high res, reduce in plot; so plot resized still has clear legend
img <- magick::image_graph(res = 125, height = 45) 

# entire legend must show in the viewer pane; 
#     what you see is what you get
# chances are you need to make the viewer pane bigger between the two dev.off calls
cowplot::plot_grid(pLeg2) 
autoviewer_disable()
dev.off() # clear out Magick control of Viewer
```

`img` is now an image that can be manipulated with the `magick` library. Next, trim the white space out from around the legend and then use `as.raster` and Plotly's `raster2uri` to prepare the image for Plotly.

Now that it's an image, you can simply run the object name to print it.

```
# remove background
img_t <- image_trim(img)
img_r <- raster2uri(as.raster(img_t)) # prepare for Plotly
```

It's ready for plotting. A few changes: hide the legend, add a margin to make space for the legend image, and add the legend image. Depending on your perspective and viewer pane size, you may want to adjust the numbers for `x`, `y`, `sizex`, and `sizey` in the call for `images`.

Since this is not in the plot, it's set to `paper` space. The left-to-right or bottom-to-top range is 0 to 1. That means that 0 is the leftmost or bottommost point of the viewing area, whereas .5 is the middle. In Plotly this is called the `domain`. (The default is 0 to 1, but you could actually set it to anything you want.)

Anchors in plotly are for alignment. If you want to place something at the point (0, 0), if you `xanchor` left, then the leftmost end is at the point (0, 0). if you `xanchor` center, then the middle is at (0, 0). `yanchor` works the same way.

`sizex` and `sizey` are multipliers. If the image is 100px by 100px and Plotly says it's 400 by 400 (even if your viewer pane is 1 by 1!!), then `sizex` set to 1, makes that object 1/4th the size of the viewing area. If `sizex` is set to 4, then the entire `viewer is that object. The easiest way to understand it is to change it a few times and see how it changes the plot. While changing it (for understanding), don't change the size of the viewer pane.

```
ggplotly(p) %>% 
  layout(
    showlegend = F,
    margin = list(t = 10, r = 10, b = 110, l = 20, pad = 4),
    images = list(
      list( 
        source = img_r, xref = 'paper', x = .5, xanchor = 'center',
        yref = 'paper', y = -.3, sizex = .6, sizey = .6))) %>% fixHt()
```

In my current Viewer pane, this looks like this. The legend seems to small, right?

[image]

If I change my viewer pane, making it wider, this is what I get. The legend looks proportional.

[image]

#### Method 2: Using `htmlwidgets::onRender`

I didn't call the `htmlwidgets` library, I just appended it to the function. For this method, I changed none of your code. Nothing that was used in method 1 is used here.

Because of the transfer from `ggplot` to `plotly`, the text size is excessive. You may need to view this in the browser or expand your viewing pane. Alternatively, you can modify the text sizes in `ggplot` or in Plotly.

For example, if you wanted the ticktext size to match the legend item size an the xaxis title size to match the legend title size, you could use the following after naming the ggplotly object `plt`.

```
plt$x$layout$legend$font$size <- plt$x$layout$xaxis$tickfont$size
plt$x$layout$legend$title$font$size <- plt$x$layout$xaxis$title$font$size
```

You may want or need to adjust the `y` position of the legend in the R coding for `layout`. Even without the Javascript, you may have to adjust a legend positioned at the bottom, so it doesn't overlap the x-axis title.

I tried to add a lot of comments in the Javascript so that you could follow along if you wanted to understand what it did.

```
library(plotly)

ggplotly(p) %>% 
  layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", xanchor = "center", 
                       x = .5, y = -.08)) %>% fixHt() %>%
  htmlwidgets::onRender("
  function(el, x) {   /* starting with subenclosure in legend*/
    gr = el.querySelector('g.legend rect.bg');
    gr_w = gr.getAttribute('width');
    gr_w2 = Number(gr_w)/2;
    gr1 = gr.cloneNode(true);
    gr1.setAttribute('width', gr_w2);
    gr2 = gr1.cloneNode(true);
    gr2.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + gr_w2 + ', 0)');
    gr.parentElement.insertBefore(gr1, gr.parentElement.children[1]);
    gr.parentElement.appendChild(gr2);
                         /* separate legend titles */
    leg = el.querySelector('g.legend g.scrollbox'); /* capture legend */
    l2 = leg.firstChild.cloneNode(true);            /* deep copy legend titles */
    leg.firstChild.innerHTML = leg.firstChild.firstChild.textContent;    /* remove 2nd legend title */
    l2.innerHTML = l2.children[1].textContent;      /* 2nd leg title to 1st pos */
    l2x = l2.getAttribute('x');
    elw = .05 * el.clientWidth;
    l2.setAttribute('x', Number(l2x) + elw);
                      /* move first legend items to second row */
    capTr = []; /* capture transforms of 2nd; 3rd leg items; global var*/
    function mover(fc, tc, leg) { /* from child index; to child index; leg element */
      if(fc == 1) {
        leg.children[tc].setAttribute('transform', 'translate(0, 29)')
      } else {
        ft = leg.children[fc].getAttribute('transform');   /* capture xy translation */
        /*capTr.push(ft);*/
        tx = Number(ft.split(',')[0].replace(/^\\D+/, '')); /* extract x transl */
        capTr.push(tx);
        leg.children[tc].setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + tx + ', 29)'); 
      }
    }
    /* moving elements within */
    /* first is at 0, 0; (it's child 1 (legend name is child 0)) */
    mover(1, 4, leg);
      /* collect the 2:3 transforms to change the 5:6 legend items */
    mover(2, 5, leg);
    mover(3, 6, leg);
    /* moving elements out */
    els = '';          /* string to store the remaining legend nodes */
      /* get minimum x val for transform after changing str to int */
    posr = Math.min(...(capTr.map(function(str) {return parseInt(str);})));
    for(i = 3; i > 0; i--) {    /* move the Drug legend content*/
      l2_el = leg.children[leg.children.length - i].cloneNode(true);
      leg.removeChild(leg.children[leg.children.length - i]);
      if(i == 3) {
        l2_el.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + elw + ', 0)');
        els += l2_el.outerHTML;
      } else {
        var val = [3, 2, 1][i];
        l2_el.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + (((posr * .8) * val) + elw) + ', 0)');
        els += l2_el.outerHTML;
      }
    }
    cpath = leg.getAttribute('clip-path'); /* consolidate the second legend */
    ih = '<g class=\"scrollbox\" clip-path=\"' + cpath + '\"';
    ih += ' transform=\"translate(' + gr_w2 + ', 0)\" >';
    ih += l2.outerHTML + els + '</g>';       /* end g.scrollbox */
    gr.parentElement.innerHTML = gr.parentElement.innerHTML + ih;
    $(window).on('resize', function(e) {
      window.location.reload();
    }); /* end event */
  }")
```

This image reflects the appearance if the font sizes are between the legend and the axes are matched.

[image]

Comment: It works properly unless I run it as a function in the shiny app environment when running this command, "img_r <- raster2uri(as.raster(img_t)) # prepare for Plotly", I receive this error:  
The image must have at least 1 frame to write a bitmap

Comment: I think the reason is that the shiny doesn't print anything in the viewer pane "while magick's image_graph is listening" to it. So, is there any way to save the legend after extracting it and then load and trim it instead? @Kat

Comment: Definitely. You can use `ggsave` for just the legend. I wouldn't save the legend in your Shiny code though. Save it one time outside of a script file (or comment the `ggsave` out in your code, so you remember how you did it).  Instead of the code between and including `dev.off()`, use `image_read()` to read in an external image file.

Comment: It seems to be working in the shiny as well after using ggsave and then image_read. 
pLeg <-cowplot::get_legend(p1) # capture the legend
    
    cowplot::plot_grid(pLeg)
    ggsave("legend.png")
    img <- image_read("legend.png")
    img_t <- image_trim(img)
    img_r <- raster2uri(as.raster(img_t)) # prepare for Plotly
However, it slows down the process of saving time.  Does the magick library have any other function similar to image_graph, which listens to the Plots pane rather than the viewer pane?
@Kat

Comment: No, but you shouldn't save the image repeatedly...whereas anything in a script file is something you do repeatedly. If the plot legend doesn't change, it shouldn't be saved over and over again. Essentially, none of the requirements of `magick` are needed in your Shiny app. You could save the image, trim it, then save the image again. Alternatively, you could save the contents of the object `img_r` as a character string in your Shiny app.

Comment: Since the plot changes constantly based on the user input, therefore the legends change, leading to considerable changes in legends size, sometimes partially shown. For example, in the above example, if shape and colour are set to be the drug, therefore, the legends will be printed partially since they become so large. I want to find a way to keep all legend sizes almost equal and within the range.

Comment: That definitely makes it more challenging. You may have noticed that Plotly combined color and markers. The second aspect of the legend (A, B, and C) is different. In `ggplot`, this represents the `geom_point` color. However, in Plotly, it represents the line segments. (Your `show.legend = F` in `ggplot` is ignored.) Perhaps, it's better to keep the Plotly legend, hide the line segment legend, and move the legend to the bottom. It won't be stacked, but if this is in a Shiny app, it's probably wide enough to show the entire legend in one line (meaning it will be aesthetically pleasing).

Comment: I found that to move the legend to the bottom, I should add the following argument to the layout section: legend = list(orientation = "h"). Can you please elaborate on how I should hide the line segment legend? By maintaining the Plotly legend, do you mean to set showlegend = True in the Layout argument? Thank you very much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249974/discussion-between-abbas-and-kat).